# How do I Transform an .xml file to an instance of a ruby array?

Tags: ruby, xml, arrays, parsing

I have the following xml file:

**/my_file.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<words>
  <w>my_word</w>
  <w>second_word</w>
</words>
```

How can I do the following using Ruby:

1. Load
2. Parse
3. Transform an xml file to an instance of a ruby array:

```ruby
words = ["my_word","second_word"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem...

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<words>
<w>my_word</w>
<w>second_word</w>
</words>'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
words = doc.xpath("//w").map {|x| x.text}
```

Comment: Except that XPath will return the Nokogiri text nodes instead of the text itself, try this instead `doc.xpath("//w").map {|x| x.text}`.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 it may be even shorter: `oc.xpath("//w").map(&:text)`